# blog.arqade.com and meta.arqade.com are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, domain-name

Yesterday, http://arqade.com gave a "We're offline" message while http://gaming.stackexchange.com was up. Today, the DNS entry is gone entirely: Chrome says ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Now http://arqade.com was fixed but the following issues remain:

- **http://blog.arqade.com/x** becomes gaming.stackexchange.com//x (???) instead of blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/x
- **https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/x** also becomes gaming.stackexchange.com//x (???) instead of meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/x

[This breaks our close reasons](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/broken-link-in-closing-off-topic?lq=1) due to the character limit.

What happen?

Comment: [It's not just you](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/arqade.com)

Comment: (Yes, I do use arqade.com on a daily basis - ctrl-t ar enter)

Comment: If I click the arqade.com link I get redirected to gaming.stackexchange.com, so it's working for me.

Comment: I've got the same problem, [link](http://www.website-unavailable.com/main?wc=EAlsGQF7AB4uDRBuBAEdFBANTh0G&url=arqade.com&w=1920&h=1085&ifc=0)

Comment: Apparently http://arqade.com doesn't work but [www.arqade.com](http://www.arqade.com) does. (I *hate* domains that do that.)

Comment: If I type the address in or open the link in a new tab, it works fine, but if I open the link regularly, it doesn't.  Using FF 29 on Win8.1

Comment: @badp `www` should just go away already. It is, and has always been a terrible terrible thing.

Comment: `nslookup arqade.com` returns "*** No internal type for both IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses (A+AAAA) records available for arqade.com"

Comment: [blog.arqade.com is now linking to the main site as well.](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8697/broken-link-in-closing-off-topic)

Comment: @3ventic ...and meta.arqade.com/q/<x> points to gaming.stackexchange.com/q/<x>

Comment: "www.arqade.com" doesn't work for me either nor "arqade.com" I have to type "gaming.stackexchange.com" it only stopped working about 3 weeks ago for me

Comment: I can still confirm www.arqade.com does work.

Comment: I typed it all in directly just this minute and "This Page Cannot Be Displayed" pops up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure exactly how it happened, but something must have gone a little sideways during our datacenter move - sorry about that!

Should now be fixed, let us know if not.