# Broken Link in Closing > Off-Topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, closing, domain-name

The highlighted link to *this blog post* is going to a 404. It looks like the link needs to be updated to point to: http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/identifying-games-when-you-cant-remember-the-name/
[image]

Comment: It's probably related to [this bug](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/what-happened-to-arqade-com), since the link is to `blog.arqade.com`, which doesn't actually link to the blog, but the main site itself.

Answer (score 4):

This is related to [this problem with the arqade.com being misconfigured.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8692/what-happened-to-arqade-com) The problem is that the link points to blog.arqade.com for a reason: close reasons are limited to 400 characters *with markdown* and, even with minimizing that link to the very minimum (http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/i) and foregoing all formatting, I get this:

> Questions asking for help identifying a game, whether based on a description, or feature list, or any other set of criteria (i.e. "What was the first game to…") are off-topic; [this blog post](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2012/08/i) might help. We allow an exception for identifying games based on [an actual piece of the game, such as screenshots or audio cli<s>ps.</s>](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5081)
>
> #### too long by 3 characters

By the way, the second link is *also* broken as meta.arqade.com/q/x points to gaming.stackexchange.com/q/x  which is obviously broken.

We *could* use some kind of URL minimizing service for this purpose, but I am not sure it is a good idea. It would be much better to have arqade.com restored to full functionality, at which point the close reason will resume working.

For now I've put in this 400-characters-long alternative for other moderators to ponder ♫

> [image]